# Visual Studio using GIT repository Publishing with API and Website in one Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a Visual studio Solution which contains a WebAPI application and a MVC Website both use a shared project Data access layer.

- Solution

  - WebAPI
  - DAL
  - Website

We need to separate the webAPI and the Website into 2 separate solutions for our Azure DevOps release pipeline but we are not sure where the DAL needs to live as this is required for both projects, if indeed we need to split them.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't taken a proper look yet at release pipelines, but I'm not sure why you'd need separate solutions. Which tasks are you using to generate the build artifacts and which deploy tasks are you using? For example, with an Azure App Service Deploy task you just refer to a specific ZIP package generated by your build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1**

If I understand your case correct I would let all 3 projects stay in the same solution, but let Azure Pipelines handle 2 builds and release.

One pipeline for the WebApi (building WebApi.csproj) and deploy it to what ever endpoint you have the api hostet on (ex. App services).

Another pipeline (but same VS solution and GIT repo) for the Website (building Website.csproj) and deploy it.

You can actually make both CI/CD flows depend on each other, so everything is tied together (ex. triggering on a commit on a master branch in GIT).

**Approach 2**

If you use Azure App Service, you can actually skip Azure Pipelines and link your repo directly to your App Services (both Website and WebApi), and specify which project should be build with the "PROJECT" Application settings (see https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-inplace-and-without-repository for more info).

**Approach 3**

Alternate approach would be to separate the DAL project into its own Nuget package and then share the code between the Web and API project. But that will end up in 3 VS solutions, which I don't think is ideal (if I understand the case correct).

Comment: Thanks Jacob for your really helpful answer. Approach 1 is the approach for us.